# How to loop over each word in an argument for perl

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I'd like to have a perl program that I can call with something like:

```
perl myProgram --input="This is a sentence"
```

And then have perl print the output to terminal, in this format

```
word1 = This
word2 = is
word3 = a
word4 = sentence
```

I'm usually a c/c++/java programmer, but I've been looking at perl recently, and I just can't fathom it.

Comment: perl has a split function, did you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong) and [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $input = '';
GetOptions( 'input=s' => \$input );

my $count = 0;
for (split ' ', $input) {
        printf("word%d = %s\n", ++$count, $_);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at perldoc split().

```
foreach my $word (split (/ /, 'This is a sentence'))
{
     print "word is $word\n";
}
```

**Edit**: Added parentheses around the `split` call.

Answer (score 1):

'split' doesn't handle excess leading, trailing, and embedded spaces. Your best bet is a repeated match over non-space characters, `m{\S+}gso`.

The first command-line parameter is `$ARGV[0]`. Putting that together we have:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = $ARGV[0] =~ m{\S+}gso;

for (my $i = 0; $i < @words; $i++) {
    print "word", $i + 1, " = ", $words[$i], "\n";
}
```

(I've iterated over the array using an index only because the question was originally framed in terms of emitting a rising value with each line. Ordinarily we would want to just use `for` or `foreach` to iterate over a list directly.)

Calling as:

```
perl test.pl ' This  is  a  sentence '
```

prints:

```
word1 = This
word2 = is
word3 = a
word4 = sentence
```

If you explicitly want to pick up input on a double-dash long option name then use Getopt::Long as described by Quentin.